# Java heapsize in Linux box

Tags: java, linux, heap-size

Can I do `-Xmx1792m` in Linux box

If I have like this

```
MemTotal:        10145678 kb
MemFree :          256128 kb
Cached :          9216534 kb
SwapTotal:        2097124 kb
SwapFree:         2045263 kb
Buffers :          243208 kb
Active:           3283536 kb
Inactive:         6224084 kb
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       303168 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359423100 kB
```

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: That's still not enough. Are you talking about the virtual machine, or something? (More is better!)

Comment: No, what I mean is that can you add more background context? Can you write about your situation, what exactly your goals are, what you've tried already, and what program you're using to query the attributes?

Comment: Did you try it? I cant see why that wouldnt work.

Comment: What processes are you running that you have only 256MB of RAM free out of 10GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to run a 1,5GB Java Heap on a 10GB box, why do you think otherwise? In Linux you need to add *cached*+*buffer* to *free* to see what is unused. If you use the `free` command, it will do that for you. Make sure to leave some room for buffers, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Your command is valid, but its a bad idea. You only have 256128 kb of free memory, that's 256 mb. 256 < 1792.

Try to end some processes to free up RAM. You've got plenty, its just currently all in use.

Comment: Yep, but I searched that SwapFree can use as java heap size?

Comment: The machine has lots of free memory, it uses it for filesystem cache (9216534 kb). As soon as you start to use it for program memory it will downsize that.